# Passing data from a virtual printer to python

Tags: python, virtual, printing

I am trying to make a thing where in other applications you can print to a certain printer and python will get the data. How would I go about making this? It would have to work in all applications, so it would appear as a normal printer, and work on Linux and Windows, even if I have to rewrite it for both.

So to recap: One opens a program and hits the print button. It brings up the printer dialogue and they select the python printer, like any other printer. After they accept, the python program which loaded the module (this will probably be a module) gets the data that the other application printed.

Comment: Are you talking about creating a printer driver in Python?  Or using some kind printer driver to provide data to a Python program?

Comment: I want to make a (probably C++) program where you can print to a printer and the data sent to that virtual printer gets sent to a python program. So, the latter.

Comment: If you're writing your own C++ program, why mess with a "printer"?  Why not just write a file?  It's your own C++ program.  It can create a simple file that a Python program simply reads.  What does "printer" have to do with anything?  [Hint: Please **update** your question to make it complete and clear.]

Comment: I believe it is clear. It would be where you can hit "Print" in any program, select the python printer, and hit print. Python will then get the data you printed.

Comment: No.  It's not clear.  You're talking about random programs printing to Python?  Any program?  What's the "want to make a (probably C++) program" mean?  Do you mean a printer driver to route data from a random program to Python?  Please try to be specific and detailed.  Please expand your question with details, details, details.  Please explain what's supposed to happen mouse-click by mouse-click.  It's not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Most Linux distros (and OS X) and use CUPS to do printing these days.  A CUPS backends for a specific printer is ultimately just an executable, which you can make do anything you want.  The CUPS project provides [filter/backend API documentation](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/api-filter.html). There also exists at least one open-source CUPS virtual printer in the form of [CUPS-PDF](http://www.cups-pdf.de/documentation.shtml), which might make for a useful example to consult.

On the Windows side I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: +1 for CUPS. CUPS works on windows limited to 32 bit Post Script. So the answer is "Use PS and CUPS for all platforms." http://cups.org/index.php